# How to Run my app on My Iphone and not on the Simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, ios9

I am using the Xcode 8 and Swift 3. My Iphone is ios9 I tried to RUN my app on my Iphone and it couldn't run. It said it is just for IOS10.2. I need some help on " how to run my app on IOS 8 to the latest IOS ? "

Comment: Update your device(iPhone) to iOS 10

Comment: Is there any opinion other than update my phone to IOS 10 ?

Comment: Use Xcode 7, Is second only way.

Comment: Change the target device to iOS 8.

Comment: Goto project target -> Deployment target -> Change it to the desired version .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check development target in **Project Target Settings Panel**.
if it is not on 8.0 then make it and run your app. it will run as well on ios 8 devices.

Answer (score 2):

Project Target -> Set the deployment target to iOS 8:

[image]